# Accessing Spring beans from servlet filters and tags

Tags: spring, servlets, tags, javabeans, servlet-filters

I can access Spring beans in my Servlets using

```
WebApplicationContext springContext = 
    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

in the Servlet's `init` method.

I was wondering is there an equivalent of the `WebApplicationContext` for servlet filters?
Also, is it possible to access Spring beans in a tag class?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For filters - use `Filter.init()`:

```
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    WebApplicationContext springContext = 
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
}
```

For tags - use `TagSupport.pageContext` (note that it's not available in `SimpleTagSupport`):

```
WebApplicationContext springContext = 
    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
```

Comment: I feel I'm going to make a stupid or obvious question (I would like to spend time now for looking for it), but I'll do it anyway: will the context be always (at every run) ready in a filter's init method? Regardless the answer, a provable argumentation is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @niconic: Application context is initialized by `ContextLoaderListener`, and all servlet context listeners are invoked before initialization of the `Filter`s, as per Servlet API Specification 3.0, section 10.12 Web Application Deployment.

Comment: This solution breaks the IOC paradigm. A better solution is to use DelegatingFilterProxy.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore it seems. On filters, the getWebApplicationContext returns null.

Comment: Same for me - getWebApplicationContext returns null. Does anybody know what to do with that?

Answer (score 26):

you can use a DelegatingFilterProxy as mentioned in Spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html#delegating-filter-proxy

You just have to declare your real Filter bean with the same bean name as the filter-name declared in web.xml:

web.xml:

```
    <filter>
       <filter-name>SpringTestFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>SpringTestFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
    <bean id="SpringTestFilter" class="com.company.app.servlet.SpringTestFilter" />
```

Comment: Is there an example of how this is accomplished using Java config with no web.xml src file?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to get it

1. `WebApplicationContext springContext = 
   WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getFilterCongig().getServletContext());`
2. `WebApplicationContext springContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletRequest)`

then

```
springContext.getBean("myBeanId");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your beans as request attributes by using the [`ContextEsposingHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ContextExposingHttpServletRequest.html) wrapper.