# inject the Spring service bean instance in servlet context listener

Tags: java, spring, jsf, servlet-listeners

I extend the `ServletContextListener` and I inject the spring service bean in it.

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{PersonManager}")
private PersonManager personManager;
```

I got `NullPointerException` when I used the personManager instance in the `contextInitialized()`. I would like to know is that possible to look-up the spring service bean instance in the my `ServletContextListener`. And I would like to know is there any way to look-up the spring service bean in the `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Where is that bean declared? How is it loaded and initialized?

Comment: I used `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />` in the applicationContext.xml which is in the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: And what relation is there between `@ManagedProperty` and that `applicationContext`?

Comment: I add the spring listener in the web.xml. `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener`

Comment: What is _the spring listener_? Show us. How is `@ManagedProperty` related to this spring listener?

Comment: I can used the `@ManagedProperty` in the backing bean. But I got `NullPointerException` in `ServletContextListener` and `Filter`.

Comment: You're not answering my question. Once you look into that, you'll understand what is wrong.

Comment: yeah! I got the answer from that link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7882181/1156041. Thank for ur time.