# Injecting session bean into custom filter in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection, servlet-filters

I have read related anwsers of how to inject beans into Custom servlets and i achieved to inject beans without scope, but when i try to inject a session bean it is not being injected and breaks with a NullPointer, below my code:

My Custom filter:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomFilter implements Filter{

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Inject
    private MyServiceWithSessionScope mySessionService;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
         SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException  {

        //Works perfect!
        myService.someMethod

       //Is NULL
       mySessionService

    }
```

My Bean definition:

```
@Service("MyService")
public class MyService {
```

My Bean with scope definition:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class MyServiceWithSessionScope {
```

The error i got is not helping me..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
```

Why this is happening? Is there some way i should "initialize" the session?, sorry i am pretty lost in here, 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

So i register the filter using DelegatingFilterProxy but still is get Null :

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context)); 

    DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    delegatingFilterProxy.setBeanName("MyCustomFilter");
    delegatingFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName("MyCustomFilter");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic myFiler = servletContext.addFilter("MyCustomFilter", delegatingFilterProxy);
    myFiler.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/somePath/*");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882042/how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-in-a-servlet-filter

Comment: @StanislavL good call. I'd especially recommend the 2nd part of [Bozho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882192/342852) (`DelegatingFilterProxy`)

Comment: I edited my question using DelegatingFilterProxy, and still getting the null :(