# Spring MVC - content-type aware response from filter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, filter

when you're writing Spring REST endpoint, Spring offers quite convenient way how to handle multiple response formats based on the content-type. You just need to register `MessageConverters` and basically that's it. Spring takes care of the rest.

However, how do you access those converters or how do you let them translate any `Object` into `ServletResponse` in filters?

What I need is, I have a Filter that is the first in the chain. And when any filter on a way to controller fails, I want to send user response. However I want to send it in a common response structure and in a format respecting user's `Accept` header (json/xml/...). E.g.:

```java
public class GenericExceptionHandlerFilter implements Filter {    
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, 
      ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Unhandled type of exception.", e);
      String response = messageConverter.convert(new MyResponse(e), String.class);
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (...)servletResponse;
      httpServletResponse.setStatus(500);
      httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(response);
      httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
      httpServletResponse.getWriter().close();
    }
  }
}
```

and as the response I want:

```
{
  "requestId": "UUID"
  "code": "err-1"
  "message": "Filter has failed."
}
```

or

```xml
<response>
  <requestId>UUID</requestId>
  <code>err-1</code>
  <message>Filter has failed.</message>
</response>
```

How can I get correct `messageConverter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @PraveenKumarLalasangi response I've implemented in following way:

**Server Config:**

```java
public class ServerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<GenericExceptionHandlerFilter> genericExceptionFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<GenericExceptionHandlerFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    GenericExceptionHandlerFilter genericExceptionHandlerFilter = new GenericExceptionHandlerFilter(
        httpResponseMapper(), getMessageConverters());
    registration.setFilter(genericExceptionHandlerFilter);
    registration.setOrder(FiltersOrder.GENERIC_EXCEPTION_HANDLER);
    return registration;
  }
}
```

**And the filter that handles my exceptions:**

```java
public class GenericExceptionHandlerFilter implements Filter {
  private final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters;

  public GenericExceptionHandlerFilter(<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    this.converters = converters;
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      MyCommonResponse commonResponse = new MyCommonResponse(e);
      write(servletRequest, servletResponse, comonResponse);
      log.error("Unhandled exception.", e);
    }
  }

  private void write(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse, Object object) throws IOException {
    String accept = servletRequest.getHeader("accept");
    for (HttpMessageConverter messageConverter : converters) {
      if (messageConverter.canWrite(object.getClass(), MediaType.valueOf(accept))) {
        HttpOutputMessage outputMessage = new ServletServerHttpResponse(servletResponse);
        messageConverter.write(object, MediaType.valueOf(accept), outputMessage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are rolling your own exception handling logic using Filter. Actually, Spring MVC already provides an equivalent feature ([`@RestControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)) which allow you to catch all exceptions from controllers and consolidate the exception handling logic in a single place :

> @RestControllerAdvice is a composed annotation that is annotated with
>   both @ControllerAdvice and @ResponseBody, which essentially means
>   @ExceptionHandler methods are rendered to the response body through
>   message conversion (versus view resolution or template rendering).

You can think that whenever an exception is thrown from a controller , it will be handled by a `@RestControllerAdvice` method. The returned value from the `@RestControllerAdvice` method will have the same behaviour just like it is returned from the controller method successfully, which means it will also go through all the registered `MessageConverters`, choose a suitable one to render the response based on the Accept header.

A getting started example would look like :

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ErrorResponse handleException(Exception ex) {
        //Create ErrorResponse based on the Exception
        if(blabla...){
            return new ErrorResponse("fooCode1", "foo Message1");
        }else if(barbar....){
            return new ErrorResponse("fooCode2", "foo Message2");
        }
    }
}
```

And assuming you are using Jackson to serialize object to JSON/XML :

```java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class ErrorResponse {

    @JsonProperty("requestId")
    private String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    public ErrorResponse(String code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @KenChan, thanks for the reply. yes, I know about the `@ControllerAdvice`, however, as you write it unfortunately handles exceptions only from Controllers. The request passes filters before it goes to any Controller. So when some exception is thrown in a filter, it will not be handled by `@ControllerAdvice` and user will receive only default HTML response.

Comment: Yes, see your point. So basically , you want to use the Spring MVC feature in the plain Servlet Filter ? Do you consider to move the existing Filter logic to the spring `HandlerInterceptor ` ?  Actually every things that can be done by Filter can also be done by the `HandlerInterceptor `  which is more feature rich and solve your problem more elegantly

Answer (score 1):

You can send common error response by custom configured message converters in two ways(From filter)

#### Approach 1:

In the filter, on catching exception forward request to your api so that it will decide content type based on the accept header and send the error response in expected format.

```
try
{
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/sendError/"+e.getLocalizedMessage()).forward(req, resp);
}
```

And your API will be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendError/{errorMessage}", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody MyResponse sendError(@PathVariable String errorMessage)
{
    return new MyResponse("UUID-1","500",errorMessage);
}
```

Where MyResponse POJO

```
public class MyResponse
{
    private String requestId;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    
    public MyResponse(){}
    
    public MyResponse(String requestId, String code, String message)
    {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }
...
}
```

@ResponseBody on a Controller method indicates to Spring that the return value of the method is serialized directly to the body of the HTTP Response decided by Accept header received from client.

#### Approach 2:

Configure custom message converter as below, and add all converters to static list so that it can be accessed from filters

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pvn.mvctiles")
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    public static List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> convertersRef = new ArrayList<>();
    
    ...

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
    {
        converters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        convertersRef.addAll(converters);
    }
    
    
    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter()
    {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

        return xmlConverter;
    }
}
```

And in your filter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    
    try
    {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MyResponse myResp = new MyResponse("UUID", "500", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        write(req, resp, myResp);
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void write(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, MyResponse myResp) throws IOException
{
    String accept= req.getHeader("accept");

    for (HttpMessageConverter messageConverter : ApplicationConfiguration.convertersRef)
    {
        if (messageConverter.canWrite(UserDetails.class, MediaType.valueOf(accept)))
        {
            HttpOutputMessage outputMessage = new ServletServerHttpResponse(resp);
            messageConverter.write(myResp, MediaType.valueOf(accept), outputMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Both works fine but Approach 1 seems to be easiest.

Comment: If you want to get message converters as bean in servlet filter, refer my answer [how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-in-a-servlet-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712093/2825798)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a help and guidance. Sorry for my late response, I didn't have time to look at it sooner. Regarding the converters, it is easy to get them also when you extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class instead of implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`. Then you can get them as e.g. Spring boot initializes them. And to add them into filters, I've passed them in the constructor.