# No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

I am using spring mvc version 5. 
I am struggling in an autowire problem. I am following a spring security JDBC tutorial. Here is the `AppConfiguration.class`:

```
package com.blog.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.blog" })
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class AppConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript
     * etc...
     */
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    /**
     * configure spring security custom login page
     */
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login-page");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("mysql.jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("mysql.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("mysql.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

and here is the `SecurityConfig.class`:

```
package com.blog.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled" + " from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority " + "from authorities where username=?")
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }

}
```

and the `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>blog Maven Webapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven jetty plugin for testing war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The dataSource autowiring is not working, I don't know why. It gives me error: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available. What is the problem?

Comment: Your datasource is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` due to being part of that configuration. The security configuration is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` which cannot access the config in from the `DispatcherServlet`. The other way around is possible. Move your `dataSource()` method to the `SecurityConfig` as well as the `@PropertySource` for loading the propreties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your bean creation code to root configuration class (`SecurityConfiguration` in your case.)

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("mysql.jdbcUrl"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("mysql.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("mysql.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Move above code to root configuration.
 
Because beans defined in servlet context is not visible in root/application context as root context is initialized first and then servlet context.

If you define bean in root context you can use(autowire) it in servlet context.

<sub>**What is mean by root-context and servlet-context**</sub>

**Root context** ------ *Context's Loaded by ContextLoaderListener*
**Servlet context** --- *Context's Loaded by DispatcherServlet*

<sub>If you want to know what is rootContext and what is servletContext and also to have clear idea about accessing beans between context
[**Refer my answer from this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712093/2825798)</sub>

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I solved by adding **JPA** dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```