# Why autowired bean is null?

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security

**TARGET**

Redirect user to home page if he tries to access login page once he is already logged in.

**APPROACH**

Redirect user at filter level rather than in login controller.

**SYSTEM DETAILS**

JSF

Spring security

UrlRewriteFilter

**DETAILS**

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597519/how-to-redirect-to-the-homepage-if-the-user-accesses-the-login-page-after-being) I have created a class to access spring security and ask if user is logged in (is not an anonymous user):

```
 public class SecurityContextAccessorImpl implements SecurityContextAccessor {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

    public SecurityContextAccessorImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }
}
```

Then I developed a filter which uses previous class to redirect user:

```
@WebFilter
@Component
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextAccessor securityContextAccessor;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(securityContextAccessor != null){
            if(securityContextAccessor.isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()){
                String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();
                ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/ASSDA/home/home");
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Filter is defined in web.xml after spring and urlrewrite:

```
<!-- ============== Spring security ============= -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<!-- ============== UrlRewriteFilter ============= -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ============== Login Filter ============= -->
   <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>es.assda.ged.web.controller.security.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/login.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Beans are defined in corresponding applicationContext.xml

```
    <beans:bean id="defaultTargetUrl" class="java.lang.String">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/ASSDA/home/home" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationTrustResolver" name="authenticationTrustResolver" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl" />

<bean id="securityContextAccessor" name="securityContextAccessor" class="es.assda.ged.api.security.SecurityContextAccessorImpl" />
```

**CURRENT BEHAVIOUR**

Redirection is doing well and reaching LoginFilter, but autowired securityContextAccessor variable is not being initialized. I think it is not initialized because bean authenticationTrustResolver is null.

On the other hand, if I declare autowired variable securityContextAccessor in the login controller, it is correctly injected.

**Why securityContextACcessor is null in LoginFilter and correctly instantiated in login controller?**

Comment: The bean is not injected probably because it's not managed by Spring. It could be due to the  `@WebFilter` that make your filter managed by the JEE container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not instantiating your `Filter` via Spring, so you don't get dependency injection. It should work by using [DelegatingFilterProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html#delegating-filter-proxy):

web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>springLoginFilter</filter-name><!-- Your filter bean in Spring -->
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="springLoginFilter" class="es.assda.ged.web.controller.security.LoginFilter" />
```

Also, see [Accessing Spring beans from servlet filters and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416671/accessing-spring-beans-from-servlet-filters-and-tags)